# Array size declarator, can they be calculated? VC++

Tags: c++, arrays

Ubernoob question:
Is it possible in MS Visual C++ to declare an array size based upon user input?

```
int userNum;
cin >> userNum;
const int SIZE = userNum;
int myArray[SIZE];
```

It seems that if I use a variable in any way to initialize the constant SIZE, that VC++ no longer sees it as a constant for the purposes of setting the array size.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: You need a std;:vector to do this with vc++.

Answer (score 1):

No way ;-), you have to allocate the memory dynamically. There are many ways to do that (I'm proposing 3 different solutions here):

```
int userNum;
cin >> userNum;
const int SIZE = userNum;
int* myArray1 = new int[SIZE];
int* myArray2 = (int*) malloc( sizeof(int) * SIZE ); // not 100% sure about the syntax
// or, better, because memory will be released automatically for you:
std::vector<int> myArray3( SIZE ); // Thank you crashmstr for the comment
```

And later, when you are done, you'll have to release it:

```
delete [] myArray1;
free( myArray2 );
// no need to free myArray3 
// Note that statically allocated memory (int myArray[SIZE]) is automatically released
```

`myArray[SIZE]` is a static allocation done at compilation time, it cannot be controlled by a user input (except if the user is the programmer....who can change the size before the program is actually compiled ;-)

Proposed solution are using dynamic allocation done at runtime, it can be controlled by a user input.

Comment: Or, use `std::array` or `std::vector` and stop using raw arrays.

Comment: `std::array` won't work, no? It's size has to be fixed at compilation time!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done usign a std::vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


int main() {
  int userNum;
  std::cin >> userNum;
  std::vector<int> myArray(userNum);
  myArray[1]=42;
  return 0;   
}
```

Note this example has no checks for the size the user has entered.

Answer (score 1):

Using C-style arrays is a bad idea.
Prefer [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

```
std::vector<int> vec(5); // Vector of 5 ints
```

Comment: it's not a "bad idea" per se, it's just that C++ doesn't have VLAs.

Answer (score 0):

Above mentioned answers about `std::vector` are absolutely correct.

But if you want to resize the your vector based on user input, you can do:

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<int> vec; 
std::cin >> userSize;
vec.resize(userSize);
```